# Why can't I subdivide this face?

Tags: modeling

So I want to subdivide this wall but whenever I try to subdivide this face the edge I have marked gets subdived for some reason.How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: you could try pressing alt f this will subdvide the faces but in a odd way but flat way

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have zero surface faces along that wall in the corner denoted by square dots along the top corner edge. You will have to eliminated them as it interferes with the subdividing function.