# Why can't I fill?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I selected these vertices-[image]

And hit the F-key to fill. But this happened-[image]

I am trying to get this shape but I can't subdivide it, so I am trying to create a face over it... hope someone can help!

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57534/cant-subdivide-face and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50452/why-cant-i-subdivide-this-face

Comment: It would look better if you made two quads instead of one ngon. The failure to subdivide is probably that the selected verts are floating above an existing face and not "cut into" what you are trying to subdivide. Did you extrude the verts to where they are or did you use the knife tool?

Comment: Faces with more than 4 vertices (ngons) are more likely to give you problems, try to avoid them and use quads. Also it seems to me the vertices are not all on the same plane, so you are dealing with non planar geometry. read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/how-to-flatten-a-non-planar-face-to-a-targeted-plane and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/cleanup.html